# How to exclude a character in a pattern match?

Tags: java, regex

In the example string `"a f e $s $a"`, I want to match all characters without a preleading "$" character.

I tried to use a negative look-ahead:

```
"(?!\\$)[a-z]"
```

But it also matches the `$s` and `$a`. What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a *lookahead* assertion, which means that it will match any letter that is not a dollar sign, which is to say, all of them :)

You need a lookbehind:

```
"(?<!\\$)[a-z]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use negative lookbehind i.e `(?<!\\$)`

```
"(?<!\\$)[a-z]"
```

You were using negative lookahead i.e `(?!\\$)`

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax for negative lookbehind is `(?<!...)`, not `(?!...)`, as that is negative lookahead.

Use pattern

```
(?<!\\$)[a-z]
```